# FFmpeg: How to asign codec of AVStream to AVCodecContext?

Tags: android, c++, ffmpeg, encoding, decoding

I'm trying to integrate ffmpeg into an Android project. Is there a way to assign the codec of AVStream to AVCodecContext?

Here is the declaration:

```
AVStream *videoStream_ = nullptr;
AVCodecContext *videoCodecContext_ = nullptr;
```

I have an error here:

```
videoCodecContext_->codec = videoStream_->codecpar;
```

Error : *Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'const struct AVCodec' from 'AVCodecParameters*